# Hibernate. Optimizing sqlRestriction

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, query-optimization

How can I optimize the following without sqlRestriction:

```
public List<SomeEntity> getEntityByYearMonthAndDay(Calendar cal) {
        Criteria criteria = helper.createCriteria();
        criteria.add(sqlRestriction("(DATE(date_column) = ?)", cal.getTime(), org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes.DATE));
        return criteria.list();
}
```

SomeEntity looks like:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="some_table")
    public class SomeEntity extends Identifiable {


        @Column(name = "date_column")
        private Calendar dateColumn;

//Getters and setters 
    }
```

In the DB I have such representation:
date_column => datetime (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss).

It's obvious that logic compares only date truncating time values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, guys :)
So if you want not to use built-in MySQL DATE(...) function and use only JPA:

```
public List<SomeEntity> getEntityByYearMonthAndDay(Calendar cal) {
    Criteria criteria = helper.createCriteria();
    Calendar leftBorder = Calendar.getInstance();
    leftBorder.setTime(cal.getTime());
    Calendar rightBorder = Calendar.getInstance();
    rightBorder.setTime(cal.getTime());
    rightBorder.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    Conjunction dateConjunction = Restrictions.conjunction();
    dateConjunction.add(Restrictions.eq("dateColumn", leftBorder));
    dateConjunction.add(Restrictions.lt("dateColumn", rightBorder));
    criteria.add(dateConjunction);
    return criteria.list();
}
```